# How to use regex to split a string by comma or linebreak in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have a React application where I need to split user input (string) by either comma or linebreak to later map them out as a list. Each one work individually, but when I have 2 different examples on the page only one of them work and the other one is read as one string.
Input can look like:

`one, two, three`

or like:

```
one 
two  
three
```

I've tried:

```
const foo = ((',') || (/[\r\n]+/)); 

.split(foo)
```

But only one of them works then.

`.split(',')` works and `.split('\n')` also works (as well as more complex regex like `(/[\r\n]+/)` .

How do I add that it should be either comma or linebreak (for both windows and unix) to split on?

Help much appreciated!

Comment: I think the RegExp yu are looking for is `/, |\n/gm` (see: https://jsfiddle.net/8xvjr2gt/). Please notice that RegExp would split by comma *+ space* or new line; if you want to split only by comma or new line, you can modify it to `/,|\n/gm` (but, in this case, your first sample string would be split into `['one', ' two', ' three']`, with a space before the second and third elements)

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you very much! Yes, normally I assume comma + space is what is required, but in this case another app takes with after the mapping and sorts that out but, it's still a nice bonus and may help others, too.

Comment: If you want to treat multiple consecutive newlines and comma's as a single split you can add it to the character class `[,\r\n]+` See https://regex101.com/r/25QSFV/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str1 = 'one, two, three';

const str2 = `foo
bar
baz`;

const str3 = `1,2,3
a,b,c
foo,bar,baz`;

const re = /, ?|\n/gm;
//          ^ matches a comma (`,`)
//           ^^ optionally followed by a space (` ?`) [remove this bit, if you do not need it]
//             ^ OR (`|`)
//              ^^ a new line (`\n`)

// test
console.log(str1.split(re));
console.log(str2.split(re));
console.log(str3.split(re));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

const a = `one,   two,

three`

a.split(/[\s,]/g).filter(string => Boolean(string))